# Get indices of all character elements matches in string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, indices

I want to get indices of all occurences of `character` elements in some word. Assume these `character` elements I look for are: `l`, `e`, `a`, `z`.

I tried the following regex in `grep` function and tens of its modifications, but I keep receiving not what I want.

```
grep("/([leazoscnz]{1})/", "ylaf", value = F)
```

gives me

```
numeric(0)
```

where I would like:

```
[1] 2 3
```

Comment: Perhaps `gregexpr("[leazoscnz]", "ylaf")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `grep` work with individual characters of a string, you first need to split the string into separate character vectors.  You can use `strsplit` for this:

```
strsplit("ylaf", split="")[[1]]
[1] "y" "l" "a" "f"
```

Next you need to simplify your regular expression, and try the `grep` again:

```
strsplit("ylaf", split="")[[1]]
grep("[leazoscnz]", strsplit("ylaf", split="")[[1]])

[1] 2 3
```

---

But it is easier to use `gregexpr`:

```
gregexpr("[leazoscnz]", "ylaf")
[[1]]
[1] 2 3
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! According to the @alexis_laz comment, I do not really need to split anything ;)